# How does one create a Deterministic Function returning a DATETIME2?

Tags: function, t-sql, calculated-columns, deterministic, datetime2

I have a table which nonsensically has DateTime values stored in Year (`INT`), Month (`INT`), Day (`INT`) and Time (`FLOAT`) columns; unfortunately I'm not allowed to change this but have a requirement to partition the table by Year and Month.  Therefore, I am trying to create a persisted computed-column to hold the DateTime in a `DATETIME2` format.  However, my `CreateDateTime` scalar function is being deemed as "non-deterministic" when I try to add a computed-column based upon it.

This is my `CreateDateTime` function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateDateTime
(
    @year SMALLINT,
    @month TINYINT,
    @day TINYINT,
    @time FLOAT
)
RETURNS DATETIME2
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @paddedYear VARCHAR(4) = FORMAT(@year, '0000')
    DECLARE @paddedMonth VARCHAR(2) = FORMAT(@month, '00')
    DECLARE @paddedDay VARCHAR(2) = FORMAT(@day, '00')
    DECLARE @formattedTime VARCHAR(8) = FORMAT(@time, '00:00:00')
    RETURN IIF
    (
        @year IS NULL
        OR @month IS NULL
        OR @day IS NULL,
        NULL,
        CAST
        (
            IIF
            (
                @time IS NULL OR TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @formattedTime) IS NULL,
                @paddedYear
                + @paddedMonth
                + @paddedDay,
                @paddedYear
                + @paddedMonth
                + @paddedDay
                + ' '
                + @formattedTime
            )
            AS DATETIME2
        )
    )
END
```

But when used in order to attempt to add the computed-column for DateTime (with the following script), it results in the following error message.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Logs
ADD [DateTime] AS (dbo.CreateDateTime(RY, RM, RD, RT)) PERSISTED
```

> Computed column 'DateTime' in table 'Logs' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

I've tried altering `CreateDateTime` down to a very basic function which returns a fixed DateTime using the following: `CAST('20000101' AS DATETIME2)`, `CONVERT(DATETIME2, '20000101')` and `'20000101'` but all produce the same error as above.  I managed to get the column added though if I made the `CreateDateTime` function return a `VARCHAR(8)` instead so it looks like a problem with `DATETIME2`.

How can I create this `CreateDateTime` function so it is deemed as deterministic and still returns a `DATETIME2`?

Comment: If you only need year and month, why use `DateTime2` and not `Date`? If you can use `Date`, try `ALTER TABLE dbo.Logs add createDate as datefromparts(Ry, Rm, Rd) persisted`

Comment: I would be using the entire DateTime for comparison with other records on other tables for other purposes.  I guess I could add a non-persisted column for this and then try a persisted one for `Date` but is there really no way to do this with a `DateTime2`?

Comment: I've tried changing the `CreateDateTime` function to just return a `Date` now anyway and it results in the same error when all it does is this: `RETURN CAST('20000101' AS DATE)`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the data type. I think it's with the fact that you are using a udf. How is time stored in your table?

Comment: RT (Time) is a `FLOAT` in the Logs table.  I've managed to get the persisted computed-column to generate using the UDF if it returns a `VARCHAR(8)`, that's why I figured it's a problem relating to the DateTime types.

Comment: Yes, you wrote it's a float, but what does that float represent? The number of hours since midnight? the number of minutes since 7 A.M?

Comment: The `FLOAT` is holding time in the format `HH:mm:ss.mmm`.  That's to say if the time is "12:00:01.000 AM", all that will be in RT is: 1, "12:01:01.000 AM" would become: 101, and the largest valid value in the field would be: 235959.999.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create the persisted computed-column by bypassing my `CreateDateTime` function and instead use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Logs
ADD [DateTime] AS DATETIME2FROMPARTS
(
    RY,
    RM,
    RD,
    ROUND(RT / 10000, 0, 1),
    ROUND(RT / 100, 0, 1) - ROUND(RT / 10000, 0, 1) * 100,
    ROUND(RT, 0, 1) - ROUND(RT / 100, 0, 1) * 100,
    RT - ROUND(RT, 0, 1),
    3 --Precision to 3 decimal places (for milliseconds)
) PERSISTED
```

Whilst this doesn't answer my question about creating a deterministic function returning a `DATETIME2`; it does solve the specific problem I was having of creating a `DateTime2` persisted computed-column to show the DateTime for each RY, RM, RD and RT value.

As highlighted by Zohar, `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` does not return a `DATETIME2`; `DATETIME2FROMPARTS` also takes an addition argument for decimal precision - this nullifies the rounding errors which were present in the original `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` solution I had provided.

Comment: You can use `DateTime2FromParts` if you want `DateTime2` as your data type.

Comment: That's great, `DateTime2FromParts` even takes an extra argument letting me specify precision - just what I was looking for!